# Notepad++ XML autocompletion against XSD

Tags: xml, autocomplete, xsd, notepad++

I know that XML Tools will validate an XML doc against an XSD file, and works well, but is it (or any other plugin) capable of offering tag auto-completion of XML tags based on XSD file (e.i offer me allowed tags or suggest allowed attributes)?

For example, Eclipse editor does this tag auto-completion very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

To my best knowledge there is no autocompletion against a xsd in notepad++ - so please concider making a feature request to the XML Tools author, or (simpler) use another editor such as eclipse, Visual Studio Code, Altova XMLSpy, etc.
I guess there is no autocompletion against a xsd, because this feature is to complex for such a simple text editor.